# GCP PUB/SUB - pull subscription with multiple instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, notifications, google-cloud-pubsub

**Background:**
I have created notification on my GCP bucket so whenever I am receiving any file in the bucket, it will create notification and sends it to pub/sub topic. I have created spring boot app that received message and processes that file.

**Problem:**

1. if i am running single instance of spring boot app that pull message from gcp subscription, then its working fine but when i am running multiple instances then each app is receiving notification and starts processing file, but i want only one instance to process the file.

Please help to suggest.

Comment: Please add your consumer code. This is unusual as the message can be pulled by one consumer at a time only. My guess is that your message is not acked properly and it is being redelivered and consumed by the second subscriber then.

Comment: Can you also confirm that you only have a single subscription and not a subscription per instance?